How to properly make relative imports in a python module?
Lets say I have a big project with two modules :
workspace/
   module_1/
      main.py
   module_2/
      content.py
      standalone.py

with:
# module_1/main.py

from module_2.content import Foo

Foo.bar()

# module_2/content.py

class Foo:
  def bar():
    pass

# module_2/standalone.py

from content import Foo

Foo.bar()

The problem is, in the module_2, if I use from content import Foo, it breaks when used from outside (say, when module_1/main.py is launched), while when using from module_2.content import Foo, it breaks when running standalone.py.
Am I misunderstanding the way I should approach this ? The end target is to have a tool that can be used as a module from an other project, as well as being launch-able alone.

You need to be aware of the value of sys.path, and how that value gets set. content is either a top-level module (not contained in a package) or it is not (contained instead in module_2). It cannot be both. A relative import ( from .content import Foo) doesn't change this; it just lets you avoid explicitly naming the containing package when content is not a top-level module.

I would recommend not trying to write a module that can also be executed as a script; instead, have it be executed using the -m option instead (python -m module2.standalone rather than python standalone.py). If you want a standalone script, write a simple wrapper that imports the module then calls an appropriate entry point function.

You might want to investigate using entry points. If you install your project as a package, pip can create some command line scripts that do the equivalent of import mypkg.mymod; mypkg.mymod.main(). Let me know if that sounds of interest to you and I can  write it up in a bit more detail.

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do


your package's directory structure:

.
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_subpackage_1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __main__.py
│   └── my_subpackage_2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── content.py
│       └── standalone.py
└── setup.py


import the full path:

# my_package/my_subpackage_1/__main__.py

from my_package.my_subpackage_2.content import Foo
...


you can pip install . thanks to setup.py:

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="my_package",
    packages=find_packages(),
)


execute your package's __main__.py with python -m my_package.my_subpackage_1

